# C# delegate to set form control from a class

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

I have a form(myForm) that instantiates a class (myClass).  In myClass I read a plc asynchronously.  The asynchronous read utilizes two methods, myClass.BeginRead and myClass.OnAsyncReadComplete.    myItem.BeginRead takes an asyncCallback and an object called myItem.  When OnAsyncReadComplete fires I need to call a method in the myForm that sets the text of a textbox control.  I specifically need help wiring up a delegate to set the control that is locate back in myForm.  I plan on using if invoke required to set the textbox.text property.
I have included and example of the two methods located in myClass.

```
public void ReadPLCAsyc()
{
    AsyncCallback asyncCallback = new AsyncCallback(this.OnAsyncReadComplete);
    Result[] result;
    Item[] itemArray = null;

    this.myItem = null;
    this.myItem = new ABLogix.Item(Config.ReadAppSettingsByKey("PLC_Tagname"));
    this.myItem.Elements = 7;

    this.myItem.HWTagName = Config.ReadAppSettingsByKey("PLC_Tagname");
    this.myGroup.Items.Add(this.myItem);

    this.myDevice.TimeoutTransaction = 2000;
    itemArray = new AutomatedSolutions.Win.Comm.AB.Logix.Item[this.myDevice.Groups[0].Items.Count];
    this.myDevice.Groups[0].Items.CopyTo(itemArray, 0);
    this.myDevice.BeginRead(itemArray, out result, new AsyncCallback(this.OnAsyncReadComplete), this.myDevice);
}

public void OnAsyncReadComplete(IAsyncResult ar)
{

    Device d = (Device)ar.AsyncState;
    Result[] results;
    try
    {
        d.EndRead(out results, ar);
        var v = d.Groups[0].Items[0].Values;

        **//Need to set myForm.textbox1.text = v.ToString();**

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What class is "MyDevice" excatly?

Comment: MyDevice is part of the control that is used to communicate with the plc.  not sure if that answers your quesion??

Comment: Well do you have the documentation for the class? at least the methods available? I think you could use async-await to simplify your life

Answer (score 2):

Use this pattern:

```
private void DoSomething()
{
    if(YourControl.InvokeRequired)
    {
        YourControl.BeginInvoke(new Action(DoSomething));
        return;
    }
    YourControl.Property=Value;
}
```

Comment: Or simply `YourControl.BeginInvoke(DoSomething);`

Comment: @PhilippeParé If you pass DoSomething as parameter of BeginInvoke there will be an error: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Delegate'.

Because of BeginInvoke needs Delegate as parameter, so I think passing new Action(DoSomething) is the easiest and cleanest way of passing parameter.

Comment: You're right! Sorry about that, thought BeginInvoke took an Action